# Ant Design, how to customize Steps component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, antd

I am using the Ant Design Steps component. I want to append additional components such as a button next to each step's description (make it more actionable).

I also want to make a border around each step's description.

Does anyone know how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Method

If you check their document, you would find that there are 4 APIs with type **string|ReactNode**

- title
- subTitle
- icon
- description

This means you can pass a child component to those props, which can be used for customizing.

Refer:

- API of [Steps.Step](https://ant.design/components/steps/#Steps.Step)

---

#### Demo

```
<Step
  title="Step 1"
  subTitle={<button>XXX</button>}
  status="finish"
  icon={<AcUnit />}
  description="This is a description."
/>
```

[image]

[image: Edit Navigation Steps - Ant Design Demo]